# App rejected because of ipv6 network connectivity issues

Tags: ios, xcode, server, ipv6, appstore-approval

The reason to reject my app is ipv6 network connectivity issues.

First, I am using AWS as my backend server. I use my domain name to connect with my server like http://ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:80/parse where X is a number

Second, I tried to reproduce the issue by 
a) Go to my iPhone setting -> Developer -> Status (Newwork link conditioner) -> create a profile that exactly same as LTE but the Protocol is IPv6
b) Do the same thing as Apple suggest. Use the thunderbolt ethernet to connect my MacBook and share wifi with my iPhone.
My app works in both cases.

Third, I take a look on AWS about supporting IPv6. Here is the link. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#AAAAFormat It seems nothing should be changed. I am not quite sure because I am not familiar with server.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

---

UPDATE

If you are using old apple's Rechability class and if you are using old AFNetworking's AFNetworkReachabilityManager class

Response - I did not implement any code for Reachability or AFNetworking. Should I worry about those classes are inside other sources' Frameworks like Parse?

[image]

If you are using hard coded IP addresses

Response: My domain name is http://ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:80/parse where X is a number. So, I think this should be fine.

Comment: In many (most?) of these cases it's a third party library or framework that breaks. Advertising or analytics code maybe?

Comment: My app finally approved. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app is approved.

The only thing I change is

- set the signing to "automatically managing signing" because my app fails to run when I change the build configuration to "Release" (I am not sure is this related to IPv6. I think it is kind of strange)

Reference for other people who use Google Map api, Parse hosting in AWS and Facebook login:

- I think their frameworks are good to pass IPv6 requirement.

I am still questioning why Apple said my app fail to pass the IPv6 requirement in my last submission.

Answer (score 0):

there are few points that frequently cause this issue.

- If you are using old apple's `Rechability` class then replace it with latest one because old `Rechability class` is not compatible with `ipv6 only network.
- Same for old `AfNetworking` library, if you are using old `AFNetworking's AFNetworkReachabilityManager class` then replace this class with latest `AFNetworkReachabilityManager` class or replace whole library with latest one
- If you are using `hard coded IP addresses` as `api` then replace it with domain name. For example you should not use api like : `http://192.168.1.11:4444/login`. Your api should be like : `http://api.example.com/login`

As Apple document states,

> Make sure you aren’t passing IPv4 address literals in dot notation to
>   APIs such as getaddrinfo and SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName.
>   Instead, use high-level network frameworks and address-agnostic
>   versions of APIs, such as getaddrinfo and getnameinfo, and pass them
>   hostnames or fully qualified domain names (FQDNs). See getaddrinfo(3)
>   Mac OS X Developer Tools Manual Page and getnameinfo(3) Mac OS X
>   Developer Tools Manual Page.
>
> Note: In iOS 9 and OS X 10.11 and later, NSURLSession and CFNetwork
>   automatically synthesize IPv6 addresses from IPv4 literals locally on
>   devices operating on DNS64/NAT64 networks. However, you should still
>   work to rid your code of IP address literals

- And your api hosting server should compatible with `ipv6` (this is not major concern because almost server are compatible with ipv6)

You can refer [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1) for more details

You will come to know that how you can create ipv6 only network on your mac for testing also by above apple documentation!

Comment: You should change old Rechability from any framework you use if possible because if that framework internally use this old rechability class then it may create proble on ipv6!

Comment: My app finally approved. Thank you for your help.